# WPF DataGrid remember last row upon update

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How do I get my wpf application to remember the last selected row upon updating of the datagrid and scroll to that selection?

Comment: Are you using paging in `DataGrid`?

Comment: Are you setting a value to VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing?